# How to check TTS existance in API 8

Tags: android

I am designing an APP in Android using the TTS features. Please Suggest me a good way to find the TTS engine existence in API 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use intent to check for Text to Speech

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
ArrayList<String> languages = new ArrayList<String>();
languages.add("eng-USA"); // Whatever language you want
intent.putStringArrayListExtra(TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FOR, 
                                                    languages);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Then onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 1:
        if (resultCode != TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS)
        {
            //  Tts failed go to google play store to download
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this. As this is the only step in my Activity, myActivity closes once the Intent is fired. it is not waiting for the result. As of now I have given 2 seconds delay, But I don't want to use delay/sleep..  Any workaround ?

Comment: Why not put this on your main activity?

Comment: This is my main activity. I mean I have a splash activity which shows a welcome screen for 2 seconds, meantime I need to check for this TTS

Comment: If you mean you check this on the splash activity then it is not a good idea. Check it in the activity that is after the splash activity.